# Where I can find outbound messaging services of Workday?

Tags: c#, integration, workday-api

I am working on third-party integration with Workday. For this, I am using Workday Web Services API. I have done the implementation to get the data based on some filters from Workday using Workday API. Now I need to get real time data when any business event (Update Employee) occur in Workday using API but don't get success in it.

I have searched on getting data in real time when any business event occur in Workday and found the following:

> According to Workday, Outbound Messaging Services are used to provide real- time notifications to external applications when business events occur within Workday. For example, the workflow behind the “Hire” event in Workday could be configured to publish an outbound message to a subscribing third- party system. Upon receipt of the real-time notification, the subscribing system could then query Workday (using the public API) to get details about the “Hire” (e.g., employee information, job related information, etc.) and then take appropriate action.

Where I can find these outbound messaging services?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Now I have edit it and make it more clear to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Most Workday documentation is only available on their closed-group community website. If you don't have access to the Workday community site, you are pretty much out of luck with getting any meaningful information. To get access, you need to be sponsored by one of their clients.

Nothing comes up when I search the documentation for "outbound messaging service", so I am curious where you found the above snippet.
What you are looking for is probably a Core Connector Integration. With Workday Studio you can route a message triggered by a change to hit the destination url. This is apparently how integrations with 3rd parties are done, for example for the payroll interface.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the Workday instance you are integrating with, you can create an integration that has "Event Subscriptions" to specific business processes or transactions. You can add external endpoints that Workday will call when the event happens. If searching the Workday community/docs, the term you will want to use is "Integration Subscriptions".